# how to update tableView when insert new data to the relation

Tags: core-data, tableview, nsfetchedresultscontroller, relation

I use 2 entities Person and Event that connected by relation 'events' one to many. in my first table view I have Person's names at the second I have their Events types. I can insert new event to specific person but the problem that the second table view don't update as well. only if I use navigator back to persons and after it go events again I see the changes.

for insert new event I use this method:

```
- (void) addEventControllerDidSave:(NSString *)typeData{

    NSManagedObjectContext* context = [self managedObjectContext];
    Event *newEvent = (Event *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Event" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    [newEvent setType:typeData];
    [currentPerson addEventsObject:newEvent];

    NSError *error;
    if (![[self managedObjectContext] save:&error])
    {
        NSLog(@"Problem saving: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

how I define the cell:

```
//create cell use relation
    NSArray *eventsArray = [[[[self currentPerson] events] objectEnumerator]allObjects];
    Event *newEvent = [eventsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [[cell textLabel]setText: [newEvent type]];
```

update table methods:

```
- (void) controllerWillChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller{
    [[self tableView] beginUpdates];
}

- (void) controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller{
    [[self tableView] endUpdates];
}

- (void) controller: (NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath{

    UITableView *tableView = [self tableView];
    switch (type) {
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:
        {
            NSArray *eventsArray = [[[[self currentPerson] events] objectEnumerator]allObjects];
            Event *newEvent = [eventsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
            [[cell textLabel]setText: [newEvent type]];
            break;
        }
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeMove:
        {
            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
        }
        default:
            break;
    }//switch
}

- (void) controller: (NSFetchedResultsController *) controller didChangeSection:(id<NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo>)sectionInfo atIndex:(NSUInteger)sectionIndex forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
{
    switch (type) {
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [self.tableView insertSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex]
                          withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            [self.tableView deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex]
                          withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

I don't really know how update the tableView correct, I update my first tableView but the second have the problem that I describe early (maybe it because I use relation?)
you can also see my full project until now at the git (maybe it helps):

https://github.com/dennis87/eventCost

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `EventsTableController` has a `fetchResultsController` property and corresponding `_fetchResultsController` instance variable. But this FRC is always `nil` because it is never allocated + initialized in the `EventsTableController`.

The update methods `controllerWillChangeContent`, `didChangeObject`, `controllerDidChangeContent` are never called, because you have no FRC with a delegate.

As a workaround, you could add

```
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

in `addEventControllerDidSave`, then new entries will be visible immediately.

But the real solution would be to init and use a FRC, as you have already done in the `NamesTableController`. Then new events would be displayed automatically.

---

Creating a fetched results controller that fetches all events for the current person would look like this (this is your code from the `NamesTableController`, modified for use in the `EventsTableController`):

```
-(NSFetchedResultsController *) fetchResultsController{
    if (_fetchResultsController != nil) {
        return _fetchResultsController;
    }

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Event"
                                              inManagedObjectContext:[self managedObjectContext]];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"person = %@", self.currentPerson];
    [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];

    NSSortDescriptor *sort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]initWithKey:@"type" ascending:YES];
    NSArray *sortArray = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:sort, nil];
    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortArray];

    _fetchResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc]
                               initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest
                               managedObjectContext:[self managedObjectContext]
                               sectionNameKeyPath:nil
                               cacheName:nil];

    _fetchResultsController.delegate = self;
    return _fetchResultsController;
}
```

Comment: thank you again!, I put this line synthesize fetchResultsController = _eventsFetchResultsController;

and the method like in my namesTableController of course I change _NFC to _eventsNFC.. entity and attributes   
but I still have this problem, what I do wrong?

Comment: @Dennis: The NamesTableController has a method `-(NSFetchedResultsController *) fetchResultsController` where the FRC is created using a fetch request and sort descriptors. - You have to add a similar method to the EventsTableController where you create a FRC for the events.

Comment: that exactly what I did as you can see in new commit I make here: https://github.com/dennis87/eventCost/commit/7614a25258f08920dbe69ff7a7eab1785a0143f6 (comments to short)
 but in some reason this not work.

Comment: @Dennis: I will look at it, but not before this evening (German time) - You do not *use* the FRC in the table view data source methods `numberOfRowsInSection`, `cellForRowAtIndexpath`, ...!

Comment: just to understand I need use FRC in this methods because the FRC is updated and then my tableView will be updated too right?
but when I create new event I use this code: [currentPerson addEventsObject:newEvent]; my new events objects save in "events" relation? or just some index that know connect the relation to Event?
when I create FRC what entity and attributes I need to use? Event and type?

Comment: @Dennis: The table view does not *know* if you create a new event and save the context, therefore new events were not displayed. - A FRC is updated automatically by the changes and calls the delegate functions `didChangeObject` etc. These delegate functions update the table view.

Comment: I have another question about what happened when I create new event the FRC calls didChangeObject there in case update I define cell again the tableView get this cell and should update himself? 

can you give me code sample for numberOfRowsInSection, cellForRowAtIndexpath because I didn't have idea how use FRC when I need use relation, I try but I get empty tables and also  didChangeObject .. case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate: don't called.

Comment: @Dennis: You have already code samples for numberOfRowsInSection, cellForRowAtIndexpath: in the NamesTableController.

Comment: I know but there I didn't need use relation I don't know how write this method and use the relation. I need relation (NSSet) because I want get specific events from person that I tap at the first tableView.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21104/discussion-between-martin-r-and-dennis)

Comment: @Dennis: I have added code for creating the FRC, hopefully this helps.